# Spring Data JPA Repository Error

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I get the below error during deployment of a Spring web application.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/projection/ProjectionFactory;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

The below link suggests to check compatibility between spring-data-commons and spring-data-jpa and it is fine.

[Spring CrudRepository throws AbstractMethodError on custom query method definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238982/spring-crudrepository-throws-abstractmethoderror-on-custom-query-method-definiti)

Could anything else create the issue ?

Below is my repository code

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntityy, Long>
```

i corrected the spring-data-commons to spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE  and now I get a different error.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;)Ljava/lang/Object;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

Comment: how does your repository class look like?

Comment: its is simple class extending JPA Repository.  Added the repository definition in the question

Comment: Did you follow the recommendation to make sure your dependencies are compatible with each other?

Comment: "compatibility between spring-data-commons and spring-data-jpa [..] is fine." - I doubt that. Please post the output of `mvn dependency:dependency-tree -Dverbose` or equivalent of the build tool you are using.

Comment: I am using spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE and spring-data-common-1.12.0.RELEASE -  Looks like these two are compatible.  From where can i find out what is the compatible jar for spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE

Comment: I found the compatible version . Spring-Data-JPA-1.9.0 is compatible with spring-data-commons-1.11.0 . I will try again after building with the right jars.  Thanks for your time and support

Comment: After changing to spring-data-commons-1.11.0 , I get a different abstract error.  Updated the question with the new error

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to incompatibility between Spring-data-JPA and Spring-Data-Commons.

Spring-Data-JPA-1.9.0 is complaint with Spring-Data-Commons-1.11.0

My project  had dependency to spring-data-elasticsearch which had pulled a different version of spring-data-commons - because of which I faced the above issue