# Configuring Spring beans

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to make an AngularJS + Spring MVC + Hibernate + MySQL application. And I can't understand how to configure spring beans, so that I will be able to use `@Autowired` annotations to my repository and entity classes.

`pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<groupId>com.kspt</groupId>
<artifactId>pms</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <spring-core.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-core.version>
    <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.34</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <commons-dbcp2.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
    <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <spring-webmvc.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-webmvc.version>
    <spring-test.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-test.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-webmvc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-webmvc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSF (include "jsf-api" and "jsf-impl")-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`User` entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "LOGIN", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Repository for `User`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByLogin(String login);
}
```

Controller for `User`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"{login}"})
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String login) {
        return userRepository.findByLogin(login)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(login));
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addUser(@PathVariable String login, @RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.kspt.pms")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.kspt.pms.AppConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I try to run application, I get following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kspt.pms.repository.UserRepository com.kspt.pms.controller.UserController.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kspt.pms.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

As I understood, this happens because I have not created an `applicationContext.xml` file for Spring to know how to autowire all bean classes. I decided to try `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation, so that it will automaticly generate all required files. But when I add that annotation to `AppConfig` class, I get following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined
```

So I have several questions:

1. Am I right that I need to create `applicationContext.xml` file with beans description, or when you use Hibernate (or Spring Data) it can somehow generate this file automatically somehow?
2. Is there any other way no to write `applicationContext` manually, but to generate it somehow?
3. If I'm wrong about `applicationContext`, then why I have these errors?

And maybe I'm just don't understand the concept of Spring and Hybernate properly. So can anyone help me please?

Comment: You do not need an applicationContext.xml file, this is an (older) alternative to your AppConfig class. Beyond that, look at StanislavL's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

1. I used IO Spring Platform for resolving dependencies and spring library versions in `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <groupId>com.kspt</groupId>
   <artifactId>pms</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>


   <properties>
       <java-version>1.8</java-version>
       <spring-core.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-core.version>
       <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
       <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
       <hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
       <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.34</mysql-connector-java.version>
       <commons-dbcp2.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
       <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
       <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
       <spring-webmvc.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-webmvc.version>
       <spring-test.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-test.version>
       <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
               <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
               <version>Brussels-SR6</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <!--JSF (include "jsf-api" and "jsf-impl")-->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.10</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.21</version> <!-- or use LATEST -->
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.21</version> <!-- or use LATEST -->
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
2. Added EntityManager, TransactionManager and DataSource beans to my config:

   ```
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));

       dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
       dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
       dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
       return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
       JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
       jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
       return jdbcTemplate;
   }

   @Bean
   public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

       HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
       factory.setPackagesToScan("com.kspt.pms");
       factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
       factory.setPersistenceUnitName("my-pms");
       factory.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
       factory.afterPropertiesSet();
       return factory.getObject();
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

       JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
       return txManager;
   }
   ```
3. Added `persistence.xml` file to `resources/META-INF` and declared my persistance unit in it:

   ```
   <persistence-unit name="my-pms">
       <class>com.kspt.pms.entity.BugReport</class>
       <class>com.kspt.pms.entity.Comment</class>
       <class>com.kspt.pms.entity.Message</class>
       <class>com.kspt.pms.entity.Milestone</class>
       <class>com.kspt.pms.entity.Project</class>
       <class>com.kspt.pms.entity.Ticket</class>
       <class>com.kspt.pms.entity.User</class>
   </persistence-unit>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

> No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined

That's the key of your problem. To support repositories and hibernate you need to declare DataSource bean with all the configs of your DB - URL, credentials etc.

See [here](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-4-jdbctemplate-annotation-example) for annotated DataSource config example or for XML based config [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm)

You need something like this

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I added DataSource bean to my `AppConfig`. Do I need to use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation? If I don't use it, I still get the same `Error creating bean` exception. If I use it, I get 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.kspt.pms.AppConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter`
error. Is this a version conflict problem or what?

Comment: Looks like some another bean is missing. Check the deepest error. You need to declare all the related beans - transaction, entity etc. related. PLease update the question and post the new stack trace

Comment: Yes, I added `EntityManager` and `TransactionManager` beans to my AppConfig. Now I have error 
`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository`

It seems like some version collision, but I can't understand hot to fix it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238982/spring-crudrepository-throws-abstractmethoderror-on-custom-query-method-definiti

Comment: Yeas, I have seen that question. That problem wasresolved when author deleted `spring-data-commons` dependency from`pom.xml`. I don't have that dependency from the beginning, so it's not my case. If I add it, nothing changes.

Comment: You need to check why you have 2 dependencies with different versions. I cannot tell you blindly what's wrong with your config.

Comment: Which one of all dependencies?